# 'Protocol not known' value error when loading data with the 'datasets' package

Tags: python, dataset, protocols

I want to train a pasta classifier and I'm currently preprocessing the data. I split it into train, validation, and test sets and I saved it onto my laptop with the following code:

`datasets.DatasetDict(     {         "train": train_dataset,         "valid": valid_dataset,             "test": test_dataset,     } ).save_to_disk("split_pasta_dataset")`

And up to here, all good. Now, I created a new Jupyter Notebook where I'm about to start building the model. But first, I need to load the dataset from my laptop. I tried to do this in the following way:

`dataset = datasets.load_from_disk('split_pasta_dataset')`

I used this method because it worked fine for another classification project I worked on in the past. However, when I try to do this now, it doesn't work and I get this error:

`` `--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ``
`ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)`
`Cell In[3], line 2`
`1 # Loading the dataset from the laptop`
`----> 2 dataset = datasets.load_from_disk('split_pasta_dataset')`

`File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/pasta_classifier/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/load.py:1892, in load_from_disk(dataset_path, fs, keep_in_memory, storage_options)`
`1890     return Dataset.load_from_disk(dataset_path, keep_in_memory=keep_in_memory, storage_options=storage_options)`
`1891 elif fs.isfile(path_join(dest_dataset_path, config.DATASETDICT_JSON_FILENAME)):`
`-> 1892     return DatasetDict.load_from_disk(dataset_path, keep_in_memory=keep_in_memory, storage_options=storage_options)`
`1893 else:`
`1894     raise FileNotFoundError(`
`1895         f"Directory {dataset_path} is neither a Dataset directory nor a DatasetDict directory."`
`1896     )`

`File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/pasta_classifier/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/dataset_dict.py:1319, in DatasetDict.load_from_disk(dataset_dict_path, fs, keep_in_memory, storage_options)`
`1313 for k in splits:`
`1314     dataset_dict_split_path = (`
`1315         dataset_dict_path.split("://")[0] + "://" + path_join(dest_dataset_dict_path, k)`
`1316         if is_remote_filesystem(fs)`
`1317         else path_join(dest_dataset_dict_path, k)`
`1318     )`
`-> 1319     dataset_dict[k] = Dataset.load_from_disk(`
`1320         dataset_dict_split_path, keep_in_memory=keep_in_memory, storage_options=storage_options`
`1321     )`
`1322 return dataset_dict`

`File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/pasta_classifier/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py:1627, in Dataset.load_from_disk(dataset_path, fs, keep_in_memory, storage_options)`
`1620     warnings.warn(`
`1621         "'fs' was deprecated in favor of 'storage_options' in version 2.8.0 and will be removed in 3.0.0.\n"`
`1622         "You can remove this warning by passing 'storage_options=fs.storage_options' instead.",`
`1623         FutureWarning,`
`1624     )`
`1625     storage_options = fs.storage_options`
`-> 1627 fs_token_paths = fsspec.get_fs_token_paths(dataset_path, storage_options=storage_options)`
`1628 fs: fsspec.AbstractFileSystem = fs_token_paths[0]`
`1630 if is_remote_filesystem(fs):`

`File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/pasta_classifier/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fsspec/core.py:610, in get_fs_token_paths(urlpath, mode, num, name_function, storage_options, protocol, expand)`
`608 if protocol:`
`609     storage_options["protocol"] = protocol`
`--> 610 chain =` *`un_chain(urlpath0, storage_options or {})`
`611 inkwargs = {}`
`612 # Reverse iterate the chain, creating a nested target`*`* structure`

`File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/pasta_classifier/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fsspec/core.py:325, in _un_chain(path, kwargs)`
`323 for bit in reversed(bits):`
`324     protocol = kwargs.pop("protocol", None) or split_protocol(bit)[0] or "file"`
`--> 325     cls = get_filesystem_class(protocol)`
`326     extra_kwargs = cls._get_kwargs_from_urls(bit)`
`327     kws = kwargs.pop(protocol, {})`

`File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/pasta_classifier/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fsspec/registry.py:232, in get_filesystem_class(protocol)`
`230 if protocol not in registry:`
`231     if protocol not in known_implementations:`
`--> 232         raise ValueError(f"Protocol not known: {protocol}")`
`233     bit = known_implementations[protocol]`
`234     try:`

`` ValueError: Protocol not known: split_pasta_dataset` ``

I tried to restart the kernel and clear outputs in all cells and tried to run the cell again, but the same error occurred. I also tried to check if I wrote the exact file name and it seems correct. I also tried to google the error but I couldn't manage to find a similar discussion on this topic. Can somebody please help me out on this one?

Comment: I might have found a solution! I didn't specify the full path (I wrote split_pasta_dataset rather than split_pasta_dataset/train, split_pasta_dataset/validation, and split_pasta_dataset/test). So now it seems to be working. I might just need to write the code three times..

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with fsspec version.

Just try `pip install fsspec==2023.6.0`.

Read also this issue on huggingface: https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/6353